# Fields not editable in Smart Mult Edit

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm extending my Fiori elements app and trying to implement "Smart Multi Edit".

I made all requested changes in my project but when I select the row and hit to modify, the fields isn't able to modify.

I'm using a root custom entity CDS, see some details about my project below:

https://github.com/pitterrs/SmartMultEdit

I'm using OData V2.

Here is my screen:

[image: SmartMultiEdit screenshot]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Smart controls but I'm no expert in that area. Try with the latest SAPUI5 release and see if the issue is still reproducible. If so, create a [customer incident](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#incident/create) since you're using SAPUI5 (not OpenUI5).

Comment: Were you able to create a customer incident?

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing to do with single or multiple selections.
The field is not editable in the back end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).